# How to get the value of the editText in hashmap in android

Tags: android, hashmap, android-edittext

I have a `HashMap` populated in the listview. This hashmap contains `EditText` that must be filled up by the user. My problem is I don't know to get the value of the `EditText` inside the `HashMap`.

```
EditText txt_iDesc = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_iDesc);

mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
for (int i = 0; i < listSelectedFileNames.size(); i++) 
{
  HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
  map.put(FILE_NAME, selectedFileNames[i]);
  map.put(DESC, "");
  map.put(UPLOADED_BY, "User");
  map.put(DATE_UPLOADED, myDate);
  map.put(ACTION, "Delete");
  map.put(ID, String.valueOf(i));
  map.put(FILE_URI, selectedFileUri[i]);
  mylist.add(map);
}
```

The DESC in my `HashMap` holds the `txt_iDesc`. how can I possibly get the value of that `EditText` when the user enter something on the editText then save it. Thanks in advance. Below is my code for saving the data in the hashmap in the database and it only gets the value of the first editText.

```
SQLiteDatabase db = databaseHandler.getWritableDatabase();
db.beginTransaction();

for(HashMap<String, String> map : mylist)
{
     ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
     cv.put(Constants.ATTACH_REPORTCODE, ReportCode);
     cv.put(Constants.ATTACH_FILENAME, map.get(FILE_NAME));
     cv.put(Constants.ATTACH_DESCRIPTION, txt_iDesc.getText().toString());
     cv.put(Constants.ATTACH_FILELOCATION, map.get(FILE_URI));
     cv.put(Constants.ATTACH_CREATEDBY, map.get(UPLOADED_BY));
     cv.put(Constants.ATTACH_DATECREATED, map.get(DATE_UPLOADED));

     db.insert(Constants.TABLE_ATTACH, null, cv);
}
db.setTransactionSuccessful();
db.endTransaction();
db.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
txt_iDesc.getText().toString();
```

If you want to fill the hashmap after the editText is being filled,

```
txt_iDesc.setOnTextChangedListener(this);
```

Implement the `onTextChangedListener` in your activity and in `afterTextChanged` method, you would probably fill the data.

Comment: what I am trying to do is save the data enter by the user in the editText. At first the hashmap has empty editText for the user to fill it up. when the save button is clicked i want to get the value of all editText in the hasmap.

Comment: Then in your `onClick` of the save button you fill the values in the hashMap. You can get the value entered in each TextView like the one I mentioned in the first line.

Comment: i did that but it crash

Comment: NPE? Check if your `R.id.txt_iDesc` is in the layout you use in your activity.

Comment: yeah..i checked it and its there.

Comment: Log `txt_iDesc` and see if it is null or its `getText` returns null.

Comment: What is the exception? show the logcat. I see you adding another bunch of codes in your previous edit.

Comment: it doesn't have error already but it seems that it doesn't getting any value

Answer (score 0):

```
 HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
  map.put(FILE_NAME, selectedFileNames[i]);
  map.put(DESC, txt_iDesc.getText().toString.trim());
  map.put(UPLOADED_BY, "User");
  map.put(DATE_UPLOADED, myDate);
  map.put(ACTION, "Delete");
  map.put(ID, String.valueOf(i));
  map.put(FILE_URI, selectedFileUri[i]);
  mylist.add(map);
```

> `txt_iDesc.getText().toString.trim();`

Add this line to hasmap value

Comment: the app crash. nullpointerexception on the DESC line even if I enter something already